# Making a snippet better with list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I was wondering say if I have this snippet where the row is a string value is there a way to make the code look better with list comprehension?

```
row_output = list(row)        
for i in range(len(row_output))
        if i % 2 == 0:
            row_output[i] = '*'
    row_output = ''.join(row_output)
```

Comment: I don't understand the indentation. Why is the `for` loop indentend? Is that correct?

Comment: mistake tho copy and pasted missed that thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely use a list comprehension to abbreviate the task. IIUC, what you want to do is replace the values that are in odd-numbered positions with '*', else retain the value. I'm stating this to make sure it is what you intend. My suggestion would be:

```
''.join(['*' if x % 2 == 0 else row_output[x] for x in range(len(row_output))])
```

In an example:

```
row_output = ['Yes','Hello','No','Bye','What']
''.join(['*' if x % 2 == 0 else row_output[x] for x in range(len(row_output))])
```

Output:

```
*Hello*Bye*
```

Answer (score 1):

using `enumerate` to get the job done.

```
row = "This Question was asked on StackOverflow"
row_output = list(row)

row_output = "".join(
    ["*" if index % 2 == 0 else item for index, item in enumerate(row_output)]
)

print(row_output)
```

### Output:

```
*h*s*Q*e*t*o* *a* *s*e* *n*S*a*k*v*r*l*w
```